# Сортировка по имени PHP

Tags: php, сортировка

```
function sortByName($a, $b) {
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($res, "sortByName");
```

Будет ли корректно работать подобная функция?

в `$res` массив имен вида:

['file1.txt'.
   'abf.txt'...]

Comment: приведите пример тела массива. что там внутри и в каком виде.

Comment: Придется изменить  `if ($a[1] == $b[1]) { return 0; }` на  `if ($a == $b) {return 0; }`

Comment: Да, видимо. Соответственно, поменял и `return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Сейчас у вас сделана сортировка по второй букве элемента массива. Уберите везде `[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такого массива вам скорее всего подойдёт готовая функция [natcasesort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.natcasesort.php), либо один из вариантов обычной сортировки с нужным вам флагом [sort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sort.php). Смысла городить огород из своего собственного компаратора не вижу.

upd.: но если оооочень хочется именно свою функцию сравнения, то просто поместите в её тело одну строку `return strcmp($a, $b)`. Функцию [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php) можно заменить на любую другую подходящую (они перечислены в конце статьи по этой ссылке). В 7ой пыхе можно ещё и модный спейс-шип оператор заюзать `return $a <=> $b`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.